# ASIHTTPRequest Returning HTML instead of JSON

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest to contact an API the problem is that it is returning html instead of JSON and i have no idea why. Everything has been working great for weeks and i can't seem to figure out what has broken..

What's strange is doing exactly the same request with a browser or postie returns the correct JSON response, but when i do the request via ASIHTTPRequest these are the response headers i get:

```
"Cache-Control" = "private, max-age=0, must-revalidate";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Tue, 05 Jul 2011 21:11:10 GMT";
    Etag = "\"e467792713ac4124f055c1719f4ea6c2\"";
    Server = "nginx/0.7.65";
    Status = "200 OK";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Runtime" = 1;
```

And the html (which should be json)..

```
<div id="universal_meta" logged_in_user_id="removed" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="meta" screen="projects" logged_in_as="removed"></div>
<h1>9 projects with 50 open issues</h1>
<ul class="biglinks progressbars">
 etc...
```

Here is the code used to do the request..

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

if(secure){
       [request setUsername:self.username];
       [request setPassword:self.password];
}

[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:destination];

[[self queue] addOperation:request]; //queue is an NSOperationQueue
```

I have triple checked all of the login details/url, everything is correct, i would really appreciate any help with this one as i am completely lost.

--

Update:

Lighthouse have acknowledged a bug regarding headers on their side. Waiting on a solution from them.

Comment: you could use some kind of client tool as HTTPClient http://ditchnet.org/httpclient/ to check if everything is ok on your server side

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you check that the **headers** sent using your browser are also the same as when you send the request by code?

Especially did you try to add the "Accept" header to your request to define that you accept the json Content-Type?

```
[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
```

Comment: i have tried setting the content-type but not the Accept header, will give it a try!

Comment: If the "Accept" header does not fix your problem, I suggest you still compare the other headers sent by your browser with the one sent by your code. Even if you can use wireshark for that, most browser also allow you to inspect the HTTP headers of a document too; in WebKit-based browsers (Chrome, Safari) you can right-click on your page and select "Inspect Element", then on the Network pane, select the row identifying your HTML page (probably the only one) and check its "headers" tab.

Comment: i will investigate further looking at the headers, setting the Accept header didn't do the trick

Comment: i still have no luck solving this, matching the headers does not solve the problem i'm still getting HTML from the API

Comment: Even setting the User-Agent the same? The only to remaining options I see are: (1) ASIHTTPRequest adds some stuff behind the scene (I doubt it, but consider trying directly with NSURLConnection instead to be sure) or (2) your WebService expects some cookie (for authentication on the service orsthg) that your browser still has in its cache but that your app doesn't have any more (This may match what is seen in the HTML answer regarding `logged_in_user_id="removed"`?)

Comment: Hey, just come back to this after putting it off. setting the User-Agent worked, i must have missed it in my testing, thank you so much, this has been bugging me for weeks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a tool like wireshark or charlesproxy to compare the working requests from your browser/postie, and compare them to the non-working requests from ASIHTTPRequest - once you spot what's different it should be easy to fix.

AliSoftware's suggestion is one of the most likely differences you'll see, but it's possible there are other things too.