# How can I send a POST request with JSON Data in ASIHttpRequest?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, post, asihttprequest

I use the ASIHttpRequest in my ios project, and my workmate use the **Tastypie** as the **server**, he told me I must post a String with JSON format as Http body(use application/json), but I can't find this Content-Type besides `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` and `"multipart/form-data"`.

then How can I send a POST request with **JSON** format in **`ASIHttpRequest`**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASIHTTPRequest post json to php server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338001/asihttprequest-post-json-to-php-server)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589048/asihttprequest-returning-html-instead-of-json